Reference request: inverse image in singular homology as in Chow groups
I come from algebraic geometry and I have trouble finding a reference to check the construction of the inverse image in singular homology, analogous to that of the Chow groups. Let me be more precise:
Let $M$ be a closed (= compact, without border) smooth orientable $n$-dimensional manifold and let $H_* (M)$ and $H^* (M)$ be its singular homology and cohomology groups respectively. A way of stating Poincaré duality is that
$$H^* (M) = H_{n- * } (M).$$
Hence, we can construct inverse images as follows: let $f\colon M\to N$ be a continuous map where $N$ is a closed, smooth, orientable $m$-dimensional manifold. The inverse image in cohomology $f^*: H^*(N)\to H^*(M)$, via Poincaré duality, produces an inverse image in homology:
$$f^! :H_*(N)\to H_{*+(n-m)}(M).$$
For notable maps (closed immersion of a submanifold, covering maps, or even a fibration) I would expect a description of this inverse image along the same lines as in the Chow groups. More concretely:

Let $i:M\to N$ be the closed immersion of a submanifold, then $i^! :H_*(M)\to H_{*+(n-m)}(M)$ should by given by intersecting with $N$: if $\sigma$ is a singular chain on $M$ then $i^!([\sigma])$ should equal $[\sigma]\cap [N]$.

Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a covering map (or a fibration), then  $f^! :H_*(N)\to H_{*+(n-m)}(M)$ should be given by taking the preimage: if $\sigma$ is a singular chain on $M$ then $f^!([\sigma])$ should equal $[f^{-1}\sigma]$.


Is this true? If so, could you please provide a reference?
